# Angularjs directive add directives as attribute and bind them dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-transclude

Hi i am working on directive where i need to edit DOM  add ng-src attribute and a model to it.

This is my DOM

```
     <edit-component>
      <img src="images/logo.png" title="Hearty Wear" />
    </edit-component>
```

I need the result DOM be

```
       `<div>
         <img src="images/logo.png" title="Hearty Wear" ng-src={{myModel}} />
       </div> `
```

Such that when i update myModel with data the image should be updated

UPDATE

`sam.directive('editComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: "imageTemplate.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attb, ctrl, transclude) {
        scope.data = function() {
          var imagedata;
          imagedata = arguments[5];
          scope.imageModel = imagedata.base64;
          return element.find('img').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + imagedata.base64);
        };
      }
    };
  });`

I need the previous **src** attribute value also to display the existing image.

Right now im updating the **src** attribute manually.I need solution where i can update via **model** variable

Thanks

Comment: Post your directive code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long reading of documentation about AngularJS Directives in various blogs and sites.

I just came to know complete flow of directives

The flow will be from

> Compile -> Controller -> preLink -> postLink or (Link)

If you want add any **core  Directives of angular(ng-model, ng-style,ng-src)** at **Compile Phase**

```js
var app;

app = angular.module('App', []);

app.directive('myDirective', [
  '$compile', function($compile) {  // Crucial Part
    return {
      scope: true,
      compile: function(element, attrs) {
        element.attr('ng-src', '{{imageModel}}');
        element.attr('ng-click', 'updateImage()');
        element.removeAttr('my-directive'); // Crucial Part
        return {
          pre: function(scope, ele, attb) {},
          post: function(scope, ele, attb) {
            $compile(ele)(scope);
            return scope.updateImage = function() {
              return scope.imageModel = "http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/halet-cambels-99th-birthday-6544342839721984-hp2x.png";
            };
          }
        };
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        return $scope.imageModel = null;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app='App'>
  <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="" my-directive>

</body>
</html>
```

I will explain the necessary steps involved in it .

**First phase (Compile) :-**

Add the core angular directives or custom directives you want in this phase by

```
    element.attr('ng-src', '{{imageModel}}'); // For dynamic image url changes
    element.attr('ng-click', 'updateImage()'); // The trigger to update image
    element.removeAttr('my-directive'); // **Crucial step please remove your custom directive attribute**
```

**If you dont remove your Custom directive during $compile() it will loop infinite times**

**Second phase (Controller):-**

Define all your models needed and function in these phase (I know i have defined updateImage() in postLink . It also works!)

$scope.imageModel = null // Initialization

**Third phase (link) :-** 
The order is first preLink and then postLink .
I haven't defined anything in the prelink.

postLink :- **$compile(element)(scope)**. This will actually bind compile all the directives involved in the element and it binds them dynamically.(vola). Everything works as desired.

Thanks. If you feel i have missed some points or misunderstood the concept, feel free to update it.

JSBin link https://jsbin.com/parote/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<img ng-if="!myModel" src="images/logo.png" title="Hearty Wear"/>
<img ng-if="myModel" src="{{ myModel }}" title="Hearty Wear"/>
```

Comment: I think you might need `ng-src` instead.